# Importing a component from npm package VueJs3

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-component, vuejs3

I am updating myself and my skills and I decided to start learning Vue during this pandemic.
I'm creating a small component library that implements the UIkit framework for personal use and I have released an npm package to be able to use the components in various projects easily.

To do this, I have used this tutorial: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-and-publish-a-vue-component-library/ and I have successfully created an npm package that once installed in my project with the `npm install <packageName>` command gets installed in the `node_modules` folder with the following folder structure:

```
-packageFolder
---dist
----- packagename.esm.js
----- packagename.min.js
----- packagename.ssr.js
---src
-----lib-components
-------Component1.vue
-------Component2.vue
-------Component3.vue
---package.json
```

I have managed to globally import the package using `import 'componentName' from 'packagename';` but now I'm facing the following errors:

[image]

Any clue about what's happening? Thank you!

**It is important to refer that I am learning and using Vue 3.**

Thank you very much for your help!

Regards,
T.

Comment: This might be becoz that package has used events that is not compatible with vue 3. If you try the same on vue 2 it will work.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer! Do you know any alternative to vue-sfc-rollup for Vue3 ? or any alternative way to wrap a npm package of a component library?

Comment: If you have created the component and wrapped it as a package then modify the code to make it vue 3 compatible and the rewrap it

Comment: This will help you in the migration
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/introduction.html#overview

Comment: The components were created as Vue 3 components. Unfortunately I suspect that the wrapper is the culprit for introducing Vue 2 code. I actually had to update the package.json file Vue version to 3 because it was set to 2.6.X.

Comment: Oh...so now is it working?

Comment: No, I had to change it in the first place to be able to even build the npm package.